# Vite/Storybook component library fails install into consuming library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite, npm-publish

I have created a component library on Storybook with Vite.
The component library is used for all our companies components to be stored in 1 central place.

It exists as its own repository and has an npm registry which is then installed via npm in the consuming project.

This is the `vite.config.ts` in the component library:

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      },
      fileName: (format, entry) =>
        `name-component-library.${entry}.${format}.js`,
      formats: ["es", "umd"],
      name: "nameComponents",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // An array of module IDs to exclude from the final bundle
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
      // Defines the output configuration for your bundle
      output: {
        // Maps module IDs to their corresponding global variable names
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    tsConfigPaths(),
    dts({
      include: ["src"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

The component library is implemented using MUI v5 components and some other libraries (for example react-responsive-carousel).

These are the big dependencies:

> ```
> "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
> "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
> "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
> "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
> "@mui/material": "^5.11.16",
> ```

In the consuming project, I have checked `node_modules` and I see the library there. Everything from the build is there. It also has its own node_modules which contains the dependencies shown above.

Both the consuming project and the component library are using React 18.

However, when the consuming project attempts to compile, I get this error:

```
./node_modules/@name/component-library/dist/name-component-library.components.es.js 1126:58
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1126:58)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|             var h = e ? e() : "";
|             I(
>               "Failed " + Z + " type: " + W.message + (h ?? "")
|             );
|           }
```

I am running out of ideas.

The component library package.json looks like this:

```
  "name": "@name/component-library",
  "private": false,
  "version": "2.1.6",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./dist/name-component-library.components.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/name-component-library.components.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the codebase in my company is total shit, I never considered that we don't have a babel transpiler implemented. I added the following to the webpack.config

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@name\/component-library)\/).*/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/preset-react',
                        '@babel/preset-typescript'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
```